# Возможно ли передать в метод переменную?

Tags: python, pyqt5, checkbox, qbuttongroup, findchildren

Например, в *PyQt5* я хочу с помощью `isChecked()` проверить выбраны ли чекбоксы

```
self.c_model = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(MainWindow)
self.c_type= QtWidgets.QCheckBox(MainWindow)
self.c_year= QtWidgets.QCheckBox(MainWindow)
        
def foo(self):
    check_boxes = ['c_model', 'c_type', 'c_year']
    for item in check_boxes:
        print(self.item(<-как сюда вставить переменные значения из списка?).isChecked())
```

Возможно-ли как то передавать в метод переменные значения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Список может содержать в себе не только строки, но и целые объекты:

```py
check_boxes = [self.c_model, self.c_type, self.c_year]

for item in check_boxes:
    print(item.isChecked())
```

Answer (score 2):

Помимо хранения ссылок на кнопки в списке может понадобиться что-то сложнее, а именно группирование кнопок и общая обработка кликов по ним.

В этом случае удобно использовать [QButtonGroup](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbuttongroup.html). Отслеживание кликов происходит через сигнал [buttonClicked](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbuttongroup.html#buttonClicked) (в него передается сама кнопка), подобный сигнал, но если нужно и состояние переключателя знать, то использовать [buttonToggled](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbuttongroup.html#buttonToggled) (в него передается кнопка и булевый флаг переключателя). Сигнал [buttonToggled](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbuttongroup.html#buttonToggled) вполне заменяется [buttonClicked](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbuttongroup.html#buttonClicked), просто нужно будет у кнопки вызвать `isChecked`: `button.isChecked()`

Пример:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QCheckBox, QButtonGroup


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.c_model = QCheckBox('Model')
        self.c_type = QCheckBox('Type')
        self.c_year = QCheckBox('Year')

        self.c_groups = QButtonGroup()
        self.c_groups.setExclusive(False)
        self.c_groups.addButton(self.c_model)
        self.c_groups.addButton(self.c_type)
        self.c_groups.addButton(self.c_year)
        self.c_groups.buttonToggled.connect(self._on_toggled)

        main_layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.c_model)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.c_type)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.c_year)

    def _on_toggled(self, button, checked):
        print(f'{button.text()!r} toggled! Checked={checked}')
        for cb in self.c_groups.buttons():
            print(cb.text(), cb.isChecked())

        print()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()

    app.exec()
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант.

```
checkBoxs =  self.findChildren(QCheckBox)
```

`findChildren` - возвращает всех потомков объекта с заданным именем
или пустой список, если таких объектов нет.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(152, 237)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.checkBox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.checkBox.setObjectName("checkBox")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.checkBox)
        self.checkBox_2 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.checkBox_2.setObjectName("checkBox_2")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.checkBox_2)
        self.checkBox_3 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.checkBox_3.setObjectName("checkBox_3")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.checkBox_3)
        self.checkBox_4 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.checkBox_4.setObjectName("checkBox_4")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.checkBox_4)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 152, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.checkBox.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "A"))
        self.checkBox_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "B"))
        self.checkBox_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "C"))
        self.checkBox_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "D"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Проверить"))
        

class Test(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Test, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.action)

    def action(self):
        checkBoxs =  self.findChildren(QCheckBox)
        self.lineEdit.clear()
        for checkBox in checkBoxs:
            if checkBox.isChecked():
                self.lineEdit.setText(
                    f'{self.lineEdit.text()} {checkBox.text()}; ')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Test()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]